Excel VBA: Button to Conditionally Lock Cells in a Range
I am trying to add a feature to a .xlsm file that allows moderators to click a button to auto-lock / unlock cells in a range depending on their background color:

If BG color, unlock cell if empty, lock otherwise
If no BG color, lock cell

I am trying to place the Sub for this in ThisWorkbook so I can place an ActiveX Command Button on each sheet, then simply call ThisWorkbook.OnAutoLockClick for each sheet. I want it here to centralize Password management and ease of refactoring.
I currently have:
In ThisWorkbook:
Private Const PW As String = "password"

'Auto Lock Button Click Handler:
Sub OnAutoLockClick()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Variant
    
    Set sh = Application.ActiveSheet
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B4:K140") 'Cells which may be filled by students
    
    sh.Unprotect Password:=PW
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
            cell.Locked = Not IsEmpty(cell.Value)
        Else
            cell.Locked = True
        End If
    Next cell
    sh.Protect Password:=PW
End Sub

In Sheet3:
Private Sub AutoLockBtn_Click()
    Call ThisWorkbook.OnAutoLockClick
End Sub

Upon clicking the button, no changes seem to occur. The Sheet which initially starts Unprotected remains Unprotected, and cell Locked / Unlocked values do not change. If somebody could help point out my errors here, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Conditionally (Un)Lock Cells in Range

I would rather insert a Forms Control Button, assign the macro to it, and then copy it to the appropriate worksheets. Then I won't have to bother with copying code to each sheet.
To increase efficiency, first lock all cells, then unlock the empty and highlighted ones.

Option Explicit

'Auto Lock Button Click Handler

' Add a Button (forms control), select it, right-click it
' and in the menu that opens, select 'Assign Macro'.
' If you want to keep the code in the 'ThisWorkbook' module,
' use 'ThisWorkbook.OnAutoLockClick'.
' If you put the code in a standard module e.g. 'Module1',
' use 'OnAutoLockClick'.

Sub OnAutoLockClick()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Auto-Lock Student Cells"
    Const PW As String = "password"
    Const STUDENT_RANGE_ADDRESS As String = "B4:K140"
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    
    ' Reference the Student range, the cells that may be populated by students.
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws.Range(STUDENT_RANGE_ADDRESS)
    Dim RowsCount As Long: RowsCount = rng.Rows.Count
    Dim ColumnsCount As Long: ColumnsCount = rng.Columns.Count
    
    ' Write the values from the range to a 2D one-based array.
    Dim Data() As Variant: Data = rng.Value
    
    ' Auto-lock the Student range.
    
    Dim urng As Range, cell As Range, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim IsCellFound As Boolean
    
    ws.Unprotect Password:=PW
        
    ' Lock all cells (at once).
    rng.Locked = True
    
    ' Add each...
    For r = 1 To RowsCount
        For c = 1 To ColumnsCount
            ' ... empty...
            If IsEmpty(Data(r, c)) Then
                ' ... and highlighted (Student) cell...
                Set cell = rng.Cells(r, c)
                If cell.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
                    ' ... to a unioned range...
                    If IsCellFound Then
                        Set urng = Union(urng, cell)
                    Else ' first
                        Set urng = cell
                        IsCellFound = True ' never reset
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
    
    ' ...  so that they can all be unlocked at once.
    If IsCellFound Then urng.Locked = False
    
    ws.Protect Password:=PW
    
    ' Inform.
    
    If IsCellFound Then
        MsgBox "The Student cells in ""'" & ws.Name & "'!" & rng.Address(0, 0) _
            & """ were auto-locked.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    Else
        MsgBox "The Student range is populated! All cells are locked!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
    End If
    
End Sub


Thanks @VBasic2008! This is a very elegant solution. I'm pretty new to VBA, so I'd like to ask a couple clarification questions:

What is it that makes locking the urng all at once more efficient than locking each cell as we visit it?
Is it better to use an If...Else tree vs And statements, or is that a personal choice?
Can you explain the syntax for MsgBox formatting? I am interested in how you injected vars into the prompt, but can't quite break down how this syntax works with all the ""'" "'!" """. I'm also curious about your use of _ both in the prompt and out of it

